# oracle: how to get the local timestamp insteadof the server timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Suppose I have a table **foo** with the colum **changed_colum** of type date.

Now i would like to get the local timestamp from that colum, I try the following:

```
select TO_CHAR(cast (changed_colum as timestamp) at local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') from foo

result--->
2016-07-08 08:48:35 EUROPE/BERLIN
```

but this print the date of the application server. I need the local date of the session and not of the server.

Any Idea?

Comment: Since `changed_column` is just a `date`, obviously it doesn't contain timezone information.  How is the time data interpreted in that column?  Is it UTC? Other?  In other words, if the data says `Jul 8th @ 5PM`, that's `5 PM` in what timezone?

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's documents at:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions037.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions079.htm#i999873

try this:

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

or

this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOCALTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I need a way to get the local timestamp from created_colum.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking... If you know the dates are all "using the server time zone", then you can use

```
from_tz(cast (changed_column as timestamp), dbtimezone) at time zone sessiontimezone
```

and then format it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` datatype does not contain any time zone information. What is the time zone of these dates? Unless you don't know this from design of your application you cannot convert.

`AT LOCAL` is equal to `AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE`, i.e. the timezone set by your application server at logon (or set by `ALTER SESSION SET TIME ZONE = ...`). If you like this time zone equal to the timezone of your client then you have to code this at the application server.